# Extension for VScode to find unused public function in the nodejs application

Tags: visual-studio-code, nodes, vscode-extensions

I need the VScode extension to find the un-used public function in my Nodejs application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the quality tool checker for JS: [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajhyndman.jslint

Comment: Or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin for TSLint.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is already accepted. If someone is looking for more detailed steps then read below:

**STEP 1**: Add this [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) plugin to your VS code.

**STEP 2**: Install [`eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) and [`eslint-plugin-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-node) as dev dependencies using below command.

```
npm install eslint eslint-plugin-node --save-dev
```

**STEP 3**: Add below json file in your project root directory where `package.json` file sits. (Below configuration in JSON file is what I am using. You can customize/rewrite it to your requirement).

File name: `.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:node/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-console": "warn",
        "no-self-assign": "warn",
        "no-self-compare":"warn",
        "complexity": ["error", { "max": 15 }],
        "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
        "no-dupe-keys": "error",
        "no-invalid-regexp": "error",
        "no-undef": "error",
        "no-return-assign": "error",
        "no-redeclare": "error",
        "no-empty": "error",
        "no-await-in-loop": "error",
        "node/exports-style": ["error", "module.exports"],
        "node/file-extension-in-import": ["error", "always"],
        "node/prefer-global/buffer": ["error", "always"],
        "node/prefer-global/console": ["error", "always"],
        "node/prefer-global/process": ["error", "always"],
        "node/prefer-global/url-search-params": ["error", "always"],
        "node/prefer-global/url": ["error", "always"],
        "node/prefer-promises/dns": "error",
        "node/prefer-promises/fs": "error"
    }
}
```

**STEP 4**: Whenever you open a file you will see below errors in PROBLEMS tab
[image]

Comment: Very good advice, thank you. I suggest to check the "Getting Started" page of ESLint, that helps configuring the plugin.
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started