# Detect unused JavaScript methods in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

Trying to figure out if there is a way to get a warning on my problems tab about unused class methods on my Node.js application that I'm writing on VSCode. Does anyone know?

Already tried (unsuccessfully):

`"no-unused-expressions": 1` on my .eslintrc file, from https://eslint.org/docs/rules/ 
JSLint [Extension for VScode to find unused public function in the nodejs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685199/extension-for-vscode-to-find-unused-public-function-in-the-nodejs-application)

Comment: Try `no-unused-vars` - that works for me.

Comment: I'm not talking about vars, I'm talking about functions

Comment: Yeah, I know.  If I have a function defined like `async function someFunctionNmae(someParameter) {...}` and it is never called, the Problems view tags it as `defined but never used` citing that eslint rule.

Comment: Amazing, great job Eslint team, great job. I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Did `no-unused-vars` work for you?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, It seems like it works on functions, (`const t = () => {}`) but it still don't work on methods inside classes (`test() {}`), and that's what I'm looking for. All my JavaScript functions is inside classes.

Comment: related: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2166

Comment: @CertainPerformance I hope they will release it soon..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking about class methods rather than functions. If that is the case it is basically impossible because all class methods are public in JS.

If you want to do this then you really need to switch to a functional style of programming or define private code outside of your public classes.

Comment: Nothing is impossible :) Hope they will release it soon: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2166